# Get single buffer from AVFrame data and display it on Android Bitmap/Surface/SurfaceView

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I have decoded AVFrame from avcodec_decode_video2 function (FFmpeg) which is then passed to the SWS library and converted from YUV420P format to RGB565. How do I combine all colors and linesizes information i.e. frame->data[0..3], frame->linesize[0..3] into one buffer and how to display it then on the Android device say by using Android Bitmap or SurfaceView/View? I don't want to use SurfaceFlinger because it is not official part of NDK and it is subject to change with every minor release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have data[0] for RGB, and linesize[0] is equal to width if your frame is standard sized.

Comment: The thing is I've tried that, i.e. to use data[0] & linesize[0] and it works for test MPEG4 file, but it doesn't work for H.264 - I'm getting only first frame and then nothing, video is frozen or alternatively (most of the time) I'm not getting anything at all.

Comment: If you don't get frames after the first, I can't understand how it is related to sws and rendering to bitmap. Isn't it you decoder that is stuck?

Comment: Look, I'm using SDL_Texture and SDL_Render to actually show the decoded image - forgotten to mention that in previous comment, but this approach is quite tricky that's why I've asked how it could be dispalayed by using Bitmap/Surface. The decoder is correctly configured and as I said it works just great for MPEG4, but for HD video encoded with H.264 it either decodes first few frames or doesn't decode anything at all. Do you have idea in which direction I should dig? Maybe I need to change something in codec initialization for this encoder to work correctly?

Comment: There may be many problems with your H.264 stream and/or your decoder, but these can have nothing to do with the original question: using SWS library to convert YUV to RGB cannot cause the decoder to loose frames.

The standard answer is to try ffmpeg and ffplay command-line to verify your stream first, and publish the way you initialize and use the decoder if the input is correct.

Consider posting to libav-user@ffmpeg.org mail list.